# Loss NaN for temporal convolutional network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, video-processing, implementation

I am trying to train a temporal convolutional neural network on features extracted from video frames for the purposes of action segmentation. My features are of shape (x, 1024) where x is the length of the video. X can vary for each video. Each video contains multiple actions with a total of 51 classes. I am running my work on Google Colab.

I have written a data generator to ensure that each batch for training is representative of a single sequence in each video and there is no overlap between videos. The tutorial I followed to do this is this one:

[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly#](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly#)

I have split my videos so that 70% are used for training, with 30% being used for validation.

At the moment, all my training samples are being used for each epoch, however batches are shuffled to ensure ordering changes and the network doesn't just learn this order.

I have included my data generator, initialisation of training and validation generators and TCN code below:

```
!pip install -q keras-tcn --no-dependencies
from tcn import TCN, tcn_full_summary

class DataGenerator(Sequence):

  def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=None, dim=None, n_channels=None,
              n_classes=uniques.shape[0], seq_length=max_length, shuffle=True):
      'Initialization'
      self.dim = dim
      self.batch_size = batch_size
      self.labels = labels
      self.list_IDs = list_IDs
      self.n_channels = n_channels
      self.n_classes = n_classes
      self.shuffle = shuffle
      self.seq_length = seq_length
      self.on_epoch_end()

  def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
    
  def __data_generation(self, video_index, first_frame):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    ID = self.list_IDs[video_index]
    
    data = np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/features/trimmed_rgb-' + ID + '_rgb.npy')
    num_frames = data.shape[0]

    for frame in range(first_frame, first_frame + self.batch_size):
      if frame >= num_frames:
        break
      
      X[frame - first_frame] = data[frame]
      y[frame - first_frame] = self.labels[ID][frame]
        
    return X.reshape(1, * X.shape), tf.reshape(to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes), [1, self.batch_size, self.n_classes])

  @property
  def num_videos(self):
    return len(self.list_IDs)

  def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(self.seq_length / self.batch_size))

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    video_index = int((index * self.batch_size) / self.seq_length)
    frame_index = int((index * self.batch_size) % self.seq_length)
    
    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(video_index, frame_index)

    return X, y

params = {'dim': [1024],
      'batch_size': 32,
      'n_classes': uniques.shape[0],
      'n_channels': None,
      'seq_length': sum_train_lengths,
      'shuffle': True}

# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)

params = {'dim': [1024],
          'batch_size': 32,
          'n_classes': uniques.shape[0],
          'n_channels': None,
          'seq_length': sum_valid_lengths,
          'shuffle': True}

validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(TCN(input_shape=(None, 1024), nb_filters=64, kernel_size=3, nb_stacks=2,return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(uniques.shape[0],activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics="accuracy")

# Train model on dataset
history = model.fit(training_generator,validation_data=validation_generator,epochs=30)
```

Initially I did not have the tf.reshape step for the y, however I get an error relating to shape without this:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, None, 51) are incompatible
```

With the tf.reshape, the models are running however the loss for training and validation are nan, so there is a problem. I have checked my data for any nan and have found none for `training_generator.__len__()`.

What else could cause these nan in the loss? Is my reshape potentially causing issues?

### Edit 1:

I think my issue lies with missings being created in the break section of the `__data_generation`, meaning that for the `__len__` of each generator, I have got certain values incomplete.

As well as the issue of missings, I think this is not the ideal way for training as it means the last sequences of each video are always disregarded. I will post a further update with an answer once I have figured out a reworked problem that addresses my fitting and general data generation.

Comment: Have a look at the data - if You have any NaN in the dataset then the loss would be NaN too

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have checked this. I have done so using: 

`for i in range(training_generator.__len__()):

  if np.isnan(training_generator[i][0]).sum() > 0:
    print("X has missings")
  
  if np.isnan(training_generator[i][1]).sum() > 0:
    print("Y has missings")`

Comment: Where is the TCN layer defined?

Comment: I edited the question to include the import of it from Keras. The layer itself is defined as `model.add(TCN(input_shape=(None, 1024), nb_filters=64, kernel_size=3, nb_stacks=2,return_sequences=True))` which is one of the last lines of code supplied.